# Run own bash script at system boot by specific user

Tags: shell-script

I have a huge problem with some script which runs sidekiq at system boot. The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/passenger/application
source /usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-2.5.1@gemset
bundle exec sidekiq -d -L log/sidekiq.log -e testing -P tmp/sidekiq.pid
```

It's attached inside **/etc/rc.local** and works but it runs with root privileges. Path to script:

```
/home/passenger/run_sidekiq
```

I need to run it with user passenger privileges. I tried:

```
sudo -u passenger bash -c "bundle exec sidekiq -d -L log/sidekiq.log -e testing -P tmp/sidekiq.pid"
```

and many combination of above but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the whole script as `passenger`.

```
sudo -u passenger -H bash -c /home/passenger/run_sidekiq
```

If your previous trials created any files, delete them, because non-superuser will not be able to overwrite them.

P.S. you can, of course, run all commands like you were trying to do, just separating them with `;`

```
sudo -u passenger -H bash -c "cd /home/passenger/application; source ...; bundle ...;"
```

but it does not look nice.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have resolved it by changing line it /etc/rc.local. I have added `su - passenger -c` so whole line in file looks  `su - passenger -c '/home/passenger/run_sidekiq_on_startup || exit 1'`.

Comment: @Polak you are welcome. but 'thanks' here are realized by upvoting the answer, not by writing it in words.

Comment: It not appears on my screen but upvote is done. Thanks for advice.

Comment: @Polak something does not work with your upvoting unfortunately

Comment: But I hope you got upvote to answer, yes? ;)
Btw do you know how often/what time is run `APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";`? I can't find any information about when cron runs it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not super elegant, but you could add it to the user's crontab.

So as the user `passenger` you'll run `crontab -e`
then add

```
@reboot /PATH/TO/SCRIPT
```

to the bottom